# jquery each loop to work out correct vertical margins

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to make jquery calculate the height of the parent then the child then calculate the correct margins to apply to the children.

The calculations work fine, just that it is not looping for each child of the loop;

```
var navHeight = $('#nav').height();
var navImgHeight = $('#nav li img').height();

$('#nav li img').each(function(){

    $(this).css({ "margin-top" : ((navHeight - navImgHeight) / 2) });

});
```

Comment: When you call a method such as `height()` on a jQuery object that contains an array of objects (as I imagine `#nav li img` would return), it calculates the height of just the first item. If you wanted to get each element's height, you should figure it out inside the loop. Does that help? I'm not sure if I've understood the question or not (hence this being a comment).

Comment: Uhm, why so completcated?  $(this).css("margin-top",((navHeight - navImgHeight) / 2)); should also work.

'

Comment: that seems to be what im after, currently it just only gets the first images values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because in your example you are defining `navImgHeight` once, when you need to define it for each image (see the `for each`?):

```
var navHeight = $('#nav').height();

$('#nav li img').each(function(){
    var navImgHeight = $(this).height();
    $(this).css({ "margin-top" : ((navHeight - navImgHeight) / 2) });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.height()` returns a number but no specified unit, like `px` or `em`.  You will need to add that to the script.

You will need to do something like this (untested)

`$(this).css({ "margin-top" : ((navHeight - navImgHeight) / 2) + "px" });`

Comment: well ok i missed that part out but you didn't answer my question i want it to loop through the elements and calculate all the margins and apply to the one it calculated, at the moment it calculates the first images margin and applies it to all images within the #nav li

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var navHeight = $('#nav').height();
var navImgHeight;

$('#nav li img').each(function(){
   navImgHeight = $(this).height();
    $(this).css({ "margin-top" : ((navHeight - navImgHeight) / 2) });

});
```